# Can't remove invalid item from IntelliJ maven project with nested modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In a maven project, I have a primary module A with several nested modules B, C, etc...

One of the nested modules has several references to dependencies I added to its POM and then removed. Each of these is listed as a Problem of the form: "Module B: invalid item 'opensaml-2.x.x' in the dependencies list.

I want to remove these old references and manually add a JAR file. However, for both these operations I get the same error:

`Source root "...\A\B\src" cannot be defined in module "A" because it belongs to content of nested module "B"`

I'm not trying to define any source root, though. I just want to delete a reference to a missing dependency and add a JAR file.

Comment: I was able to remove the invalid library references by manually editing A's .iml file. However, trying to add a JAR to B still triggers the error, as IntelliJ seems to somehow assume I want to add B's source folder as a source for A.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking the parent module in the project panel and choosing "Maven->Reimport"?

Comment: No. I'll try that.

Comment: Oh, that button. Yes, I did, actually.

Answer (score 4):

1. Try right-clicking the parent module in the project panel and choosing "Maven->Reimport"
2. If that does not work then:

   - close the project
   - delete the `.idea` directory and all `.iml` files
   - Use "File/New/Project from existing sources..." to recreate the project
   - "Import project from external model"
   - select "Maven"

For one reason or another Idea's module structure can become messed up and it's easier to just reimport it. This generally happens when you have renamed a module or module directory.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the module which intellij thinks that the folder belongs to, press F4 to open module settings, on the right hand side is a list of content-roots, e.g. 'Source Folders' and 'Excluded Folders', there should be one which is trying to claim the folder, just click the little X button to remove the association.